# How to import components dynamically in remix.js

Tags: remix.run

I have a situation where I need to load components dynamically on a page. the page can have any components from at least 20 types of components, but it can be added/removed from the CMS. So I need to fetch the page from the API, and whatever components that page has will load dynamically when the page runs. e.g bellow code

```
export async function loader({ request, params }) {
  const page = await getPage(host, paramas.id);

/* Page Data (screenshot of the API attached at the bottom)

{
  "data": {
    "title": "My Page",
    "slug": "my-page",
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "slider",
        "data": {
          "name": "Image Slider",
          "images": [ ...images array...]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "menu",
        "data": {
          "name": "Food Menu",
          "items": [...items array...]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "menu",
        "data": {
          "name": "Desert Menu",
         "items": [...items array...]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "faqs",
        "data": {
          "name": "Faqs",
          "question": [...questions array...]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

 */



   }
  }


  return json({
   page: page,
  });
}

export default function Index() {
  const { page } = useLoaderData();

  return (<main id="main">
    {page.components.map(function(component, i) {
       <component.type data={page.components[i].data}/>
    })};
  </main>);
}
```

So how do I import these components dynamically because I don't know what are different components added into this page, therefore I can't import them on top before the page is fetched from the API.

Screenshot of API response
[image]

Comment: I believe the feature you are asking about is called [lazy component loading](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy). Can you [edit] to provide an example of the `page` data you are rendering from? I find it difficult to believe you don't know ahead of time all the possible `component.type` options there are for your app to render.

Comment: Where do these "menu", "slider", and "faqs" components reside, in relation to the route loader and `Index` component?

Comment: I am trying to build an app that will host restaurant menus. So multiple restaurant menus will render form the same code depending on the restaurant that is selected. e.g restaurantA.menu , and restaurnatB.menu , both will be rendered from the same page, but depending on different components that are added there from the CMS/API, it will render the page. there could be 20 to 25 different types of component from a simple intro section to a detailed food menu or an faqs accordion list. most pages/menus would have 4 to 5 different components. therefor I don't want to import all 20/25 components

Comment: Components can reside in `~/components/` directory. each component would accept `data` prop that will be passed from the page data when we loop through  components from page data. in CMS there is ability to add slider, faqs accordion, intro section, menu, video, newsletter form and few other type of components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the components and create a "lookup" and [Choose the type at runtime](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) or use the [Lazy Component Loading](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy) to dynamically load only what you need, when it is needed.

### Choose the Type at Runtime

Import all of the components and create a lookup object. Larger footprint/memory usage, but no loading later.

Example:

```
...
import {
  ...,
  Faqs,
  Menu,
  Slider,
  ...
} from '../components';

const components = {
  ...,
  faqs: Faqs,
  menu: Menu,
  slider: Slider,
  ...
};

export default function Index() {
  const { page } = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <main id="main">
      {page.components
        .filter(({ type }) => !!components[type])
        .map(({ data, type }) => {
          const Component = components[type];

          return <Component key={type} data={data} />;
        })
      }
    </main>
  );
}
```

### Lazy Loading Components

Import the components and create a lookup object. Code-splitting, smaller size, but will need to load chunks later.

Example:

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
...

const components = {
  ...,
  faqs: lazy(() => import('../components/Faqs'));,
  menu: lazy(() => import('../components/Menu'));,
  slider: lazy(() => import('../components/Slider'));,
  ...
};

export default function Index() {
  const { page } = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <main id="main">
      {page.components
        .filter(({ type }) => !!components[type])
        .map(({ data, type }) => {
          const Component = components[type];

          return (
            <Suspense key={type} fallback={<Loading />}>
              <Component data={data} />
            </Suspense>
          );
        })
      }
    </main>
  );
}
```